# Проблема при установке mysql-service на Kali Linux

Tags: mysql

При установке получаю:

```
  # apt-get install mysql-server
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Некоторые пакеты невозможно установить. Возможно, вы просите невозможного,
или же используете нестабильную версию дистрибутива, где запрошенные вами
пакеты ещё не созданы или были удалены из Incoming.
Следующая информация, возможно, поможет вам:

Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 mysql-server : Зависит: mysql-server-5.5 но он не будет установлен
E: Невозможно исправить ошибки, у вас отложены (held) битые пакеты.
```

Но, mysql-client встал нормально:

```
apt-get install mysql-client
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Уже установлен пакет mysql-client самой новой версии (5.5.43-0+deb8u1).
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 3 пакетов не обновлено.
```

Мой список репозиториев:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb http://old.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
deb http://old.kali.org/kali moto main non-free contrib
```

Вот что выдает команда:

```
apt show mysql-server-5.5
Package: mysql-server-5.5
Version: 5.5.43-0+deb8u1
Priority: optional
Section: database
Source: mysql-5.5
Maintainer: Debian MySQL Maintainers <pkg-mysql-maint@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 32,4 MB
Provides: virtual-mysql-server
Pre-Depends: adduser (>= 3.40), debconf, mysql-common (>= 5.5.43-0+deb8u1)
Depends: initscripts (>= 2.88dsf-13.3), libdbi-perl, lsb-base (>= 3.0-10), mysql-client-5.5 (>= 5.5.43-0+deb8u1), mysql-server-core-5.5 (>= 5.5.43-0+deb8u1), passwd, perl (>= 5.6), psmisc, debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0, libc6 (>= 2.17), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
Recommends: libhtml-template-perl
Suggests: mailx, tinyca
Breaks: libmysqlclient-dev (<< 5.5.17~), mysql-client-5.1, mysql-server (<< 5.5.43-0+deb8u1), mysql-server-5.1, virtual-mysql-server
Replaces: libmysqlclient-dev (<< 5.5.17~), mysql-client-5.1, mysql-server (<< 5.5.43-0+deb8u1), mysql-server-5.0, mysql-server-5.1, virtual-mysql-server
Homepage: http://dev.mysql.com/
Tag: network::server, protocol::db:mysql, role::program, works-with::db
Download-Size: 1 762 kB
APT-Sources: http://old.kali.org/kali sana/main amd64 Packages
Description: MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
 MySQL is a fast, stable and true multi-user, multi-threaded SQL database
 server. SQL (Structured Query Language) is the most popular database query
 language in the world. The main goals of MySQL are speed, robustness and
 ease of use.

 This package contains all the infrastructure needed to setup system
 databases.

N: Есть 1 дополнительная запись........ Используйте «-a» для просмотра



#apt-get update 
Сущ:1 http://old.kali.org/kali sana InRelease                                    
Сущ:2 http://old.kali.org/kali moto InRelease                                                                             
Сущ:3 http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease                                                               
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово  



# apt-get install mysql-server-5.5
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Некоторые пакеты невозможно установить. Возможно, вы просите невозможного,
или же используете нестабильную версию дистрибутива, где запрошенные вами
пакеты ещё не созданы или были удалены из Incoming.
Следующая информация, возможно, поможет вам:

Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 mysql-server-5.5 : ПредЗависит: mysql-common (>= 5.5.43-0+deb8u1) но он не будет установлен
                    Зависит: mysql-client-5.5 (>= 5.5.43-0+deb8u1) но он не будет установлен
E: Невозможно исправить ошибки, у вас отложены (held) битые пакеты.


# service mysql status
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql; generated; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2017-12-20 17:14:09 EST; 1h 0min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1502 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service

дек 20 17:14:09 kali systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon...
дек 20 17:14:09 kali systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.


# mysql -u root 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Не понимаю в чем проблема

Comment: С тех пор как злые силы Оракула захватили контроль над mysql-server, все кто на стороне добра и пушистых кроликов стараются перейти на mariadb-server.

Comment: не понимаю что ты делаешь, зачем ты ставишь mysql-server, если у тебя уже стоит mysql-server-5.5, и как написал коментатор выше ставь mariadb, а это всё снеси. Не понимаю зачем тебе kali